# Resolving Address Space is already occupied error using Cygwin and Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, cygwin

I keep getting the same type of error messages and I have really done all I can to get rid of them.  The message is as follows, only the module can vary at times:

```
ruby 5740 child_info_fork::abort: address space needed by 'date_core.so' (0x600000) is already occupied
```

These messages occur at various times when trying to run Rails, such as “rails console”.
I am running the following environment:

- Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit
- Cygwin Net using setup 2.774 (installed from Internet mirrors)
- Ruby 1.9.3p392
- Rails 3.2.11

I have taken the following steps attempting to fix this:

- Deleted all BLODA and restarted, including Norton 360 and Malwarebytes.  (BLODA is Big List of Dodgy Apps.)
- Deleted and reinstalled Cygwin.
- Executed “rvm implode” and rebuilt the RVM and Ruby on Rails environment.
- Used CMD & ASH to run “peflagsall” & “rebaseall”.  Ran “rubyrebase”. Restarted.
- Used FIND to build a file of all *.so & *.dll files.  Ran “rebase -T”.  Restarted.  This has also been done using the “-b 0x77000000” switch.
- Used same file to create “to_peflags” script issuing peflags against each individual file.  Restarted.

All repair attempts have been futile.  At times, “rebase -si |grep ‘*’” would be clean.  Any attempt to run “rails console” or similar commands results in Address Space Occupied messages.  Subsequent “rebase -si” would then again show conflicts.
I have been trying to run “peflags” against the Ruby modules, but I only get “skipped because could not open” error messages there.  File permissions and ACL both show correct permissions.  The same error occurs whether or not Administrator is used.

This is pretty frustrating.  I would like to fix my current environment, but I am considering moving to MSYS or SFU, but I don’t know if either of those are decent options.  I am also considering going native UNIX, but I’ll leap off the cliff when I get to it.

For now, does anyone have a fix for this specific error for me?  Thanks…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used procexp to monitor "rails console" execution.  Bash is calling cmd.exe to run the rails.bat file.  Cmd.exe runs in ASLR mode.  Used Microsoft EMET 3.0 to turn off mandatory ASLR and bottom up ASLR for both bash and cmd.  Cmd.exe still runs in ASLR mode.  It must be compiled that way.

Updated registry to set HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Memory Management\MoveImages to 0, -1 then 1.  0 caused system problems.  -1 had no effect.  1, which was supposed to be the default, helped somewhat as long as EMET changes were in place.  But, it was unreliable as Address Space Occupied would eventually recur.

Decided to attempt to install a command processor that either didn’t require ASLR or allowed me to disable it using PE flags.  I installed TCC/LE and attempted to get Cygwin Bash to use it to process .bat files.  I tried using the path variable, the COMSPEC variable and changes to batfile and cmdfile in the registry all to no effect.  Cygwin Bash must either have it hard coded or some nonobvious control.

My fix is to replace my environment.  I know I will eventually migrate to some Unix, but for now I am converting to MinGW/MSYS and RubyStack.  All I want to do is to get a stable RoR (Ruby on Rails) environment running for today.  I don’t see that happening using Cygwin with Windows 7 Ultimate.  I keep running into too many problems and this one is a very, very tough nut to crack.  Thanks…

Comment: So far, I have to strongly recommend MSYS and RubyStack.  After one day, I have the entire environment up and running without any problems.  This is a much better experience than the Cygwin solution for what I am doing at least.

Comment: MSYS/MinGW became mostly unnecessary and weighty.  I am using RubyStack alone.  RVM is missing because it is UNIX only, so I am using PIK, a Windows replacement.  Probably the only big deal here is that I won't have a UNIX compile/link environment but, with RubyStack, that doesn't seem to be a problem.  If it becomes an issue, I will need to look at MSYS again.